# In Datatables JQuery and Ajax, DataTable(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I get the following error in my ASP.NET MVC project. There is a reference in the page to to the *.js file. I tried almost every solution on the internet for this problem, I could find.

From the source code of the page when it is loaded in the browser, it seems to be in correct order and loaded once:

```
<script src="/Scripts/old/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <!-- I tried new and old jquery Version -->
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/bootbox.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The Code (index.cshtml):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#customers').DataTable()({
    ajax: {
      url: '/api/customers',
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [{
      data: "name",
      render: function(data, type, customer) {
        return "<a href='/customers/edit/" + customer.id + "'>" + customer.name + "</a>";
      }
    }, {
      data: "name"
    }, {
      data: "id",
      render: function(data) {
        return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-customer-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
      }
    }]
  });

  // More Code
});
```

The error, from the developer console of Chrome:

> Customers:79 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...) is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (Customers:79)
>       at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:447)
>       at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:118)

Any suggestions?

OK, **solved**. First comment was right.

*$('#customers').DataTable({* instead of *$('#customers').DataTable()({*

Comment: It's possibly because your syntax is wrong. Instead of `$('#customers').DataTable()({...` try `$('#customers').DataTable({...`. If you still get an error after that it's because your script include paths are wrong.

Comment: It could also be possible that you have the wrong version of jquery. Have you got a version of jquery.min loaded?

Comment: @JamesS I think you mean jquery.slim - .min would be fine.  *but* there could be *another* version of jquery being loaded later, eg in a bundle or by the page "template" (though OP does say "loaded once", so presumably checked for this)

Comment: You'll definitely want to use jquery 3.3 or later with boostrap4 (I may be mistaken, but 1.10 seems woefully out of date)

Comment: Error `$(...).DataTable is not function` = data tables not loaded.  Error `$(...).DataTable(...) is not a function` = calling a function on the result of DataTable() (ie the incorrect syntax of `.DataTable()({})` (confirming first comment above and confrming that the scripts are loaded correctly)

Comment: First comment was right. It works now. I have also changed the JQuery Version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import those scripts before the Rendering scripts section.

Comment: If that was the problem the error would be complaining that jQuery/$ wasn't defined, not DataTables.

Comment: you're right, my bad I assuming things and didn't try my assumption first. I think your comment above about the wrong syntax is could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and it was making me paranoid it only happened sometimes. It turned out that

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

was being called multiple times.

After a reinstantiation of this bundle, seems that things got reset, and the datatable loses access to some of its functionality.

Such repetition was happening several times, because it was being called on the main container page, and also in the sub modal dialogs and partial views inside it.

I had to devise a way to organize my code in such a fashion that I don't need to reinstantiate the bundle in the sub contents.